# Capitalization of Brand Names

Tags: brands, camel-case

I work at a large church where we have recently added some new public spaces, including a bookstore and a connection center. Both have their own names: The Source and The Hub. In their designed logos, "the" is shown as lowercase, as you can see in the attached rendering of the spaces.

[image: Rendering]

Several of us are debating whether or not the "t" in "the" should be capitalized when not using the logo, but just referencing the bookstore and connection center in print (for example, in our bulletin: *Please sign up for a community group this fall in The Hub.*) We've talked about the usage of CamelCase, but weren't sure if it really applies in this instance. We would love your thoughts and feedback.

Comment: It's entirely your choice. Just down the road from me is [**the Hawth**](http://www.parkwoodtheatres.co.uk/theatre/Default.aspx?zid=2) theatre/entertainment complex. If you follow that link you'll see their main "logo" (equivalent to the signage uses in your picture) only capitalises the letter **H**. In normal text within the site, they also capitalise the first letter of **The** (as does [the relevant Wikipesia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawth_Theatre)), but references in local newspapers, for example, often don't. In short - the whole issue is Primarily Opinion-based.

Comment: I was afraid of that! We have too many opinions as it is. Ha! Thank you for your input and for the link to reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the name is ***Hub*** and you are referring to it as "the ***Hub***" then "the" doesn't need to be capitalized, if on the other hand the full name is ***The Hub***, traditionally "the" should be capitalized. Now if you aren't terribly concerned about tradition you can choose to actively have "the" be lowercase as part of the name, like the people who include numbers in place of letters or the squiggle formerly known as Prince.